# When I clicked on 'viewall' submit button on html it goes to 'RestInfo url' and show NoReverseMatch at error Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

**Template Code**

```
<a href="{% url 'ViewAll' cust.custId %}" <button class="btn  cart viewall">View All</button></a>
<a href="{% url 'RestInfo' rest.restId cust.custId   %}" style="color: #000000;">RestInfo</button></a>
```

**url.py**

```
path('ViewAll/<str:mycid>',views.ViewAll,name='ViewAll')

path('myRest/<int:myid>/<str:cid>',views.RestInfo,name='RestInfo'),
```

**views.py**

```
def ViewAll(request,mycid):
print("Welcome",mycid)
rests= Restaurant.objects.all()
return render(request,'viewall.html',{'rests':rests})

def RestInfo(request,myid=None,cid=None):
rests= Restaurant.objects.filter(restId=myid)
return render(request,"restInfo.html",{'rest':rests[0]})
```

> When I Clicked on button in which viewll url is given then it goes to restinfo and shows me noreversematch error

Answer (score -1):

Before going deeper into Django, study better Python and its code style.
For the error you're getting, basically you are passing mycid to the view but you are not using it so remove that mycid from url and use just `all/`  as path

Comment: But I want to use mycid in viewall().I will write logic once mycid will be printed in consol